# Determining length of roads that fall under low elevation using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, arcgis-9.3, elevation, sea-level-rise

I am working on a project on sea level rise impacts of roads. Basically I need to determine length of roads that fall under low elevation (from 1m to 5m elevation).

I have a DEM file and road shapefile. I first converted DEM to integer and then raster to polygon. Then I tried to intersect my polygon with polyline but got error as output.

If I am going wrong somewhere can you suggest an alternative way of doing such analysis?

Comment: Probably not the right way around... try selecting from the DEM values less than (or equal to) 5 then use IsNull to produce a binary raster - convert that to polygon and remove the outside area and intersect *that* with your roads. I'd say there's some undefined or mismatched spatial reference in there somewhere so be cautious of that.

Comment: Since you "got error as output" at this attempt, there is a chance that you might again.  Whenever asking for help I think it is important to include any error messages as part of your question.  There is an **edit** button beneath your question to enable you to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to a question the other day relating to rising water levels. You could likely use the Interpolate Shape tool (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Interpolate_Shape/00q90000006m000000/) in some fashion.

The simplest way would probably be to reclass the dem (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Reclassify/009z000000sr000000/). If you reclassify 0-5 as 1, and the rest as null, then convert your reclassified raster to polygon (http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000008000000), then use this polygon to clip your roads layer (http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//000800000004000000), you should get just those low lying road segments.